# Potential Energy and Antimatter anihallation

Tags: energy, potential-energy

Apologies if I've misunderstood anything fundamental, but the following has been on my mind for a while:
Imagine  the following scenario:

Take two matter objects of identical mass etc. Now one is moved further from the earth, thus (as I understand it) increasing the gravitational potential energy. Now both interact with antimatter to annihilate and release energy.

Do we violate the law of conservation of energy?

Comment: Which way are you assuming gravity acts on antimatter?

Comment: @probably_someone not making any assumptions. If the behaviour or properties of antimatter is the answer would enjoy reading that answer..

Comment: The answer is no, but it without hearing your argument about why it might violate energy conservation, I’m not sure what you don’t understand.

Comment: @G. Smith I'm assuming the same amount of energy is released with each interaction, and thus the energy that initially was put into lifting one of the objects is 'lost'; I'm aware that it could be more energy is released, or that I'm misunderstanding how potential energy works.